# how to access log4j property in all class?

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j in my application. Now I have created property file.How to access this property file in all Java classes. Can anyone please explain me about it?

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${rootPath}WEB-INF/logs/MyLog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

public class log4jExample{
  /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                      log4jExample.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args)
                throws IOException,SQLException{

     log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
     log.info("Hello this is an info message");
  }
}
```

Comment: what is ${rootPath} refers to in your configuration. Double check it.

Comment: i have intilized that in servlet context lisner

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your web.xml if you havent added that already

```
    <context-param>
<param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>./conf/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
<!-- Refresh log4j configuration every 5 minutes. -->
<param-value>300000</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your catalina.log for any errors. Make sure that log4j is initialized correctly. If you have multilpe log4j jar files (one in your context and another in tomcat/lib) it may not have initialized properly. Try deleting duplicate jars